# Show that two matrices are strongly shift equivalent

Tags: graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics, adjacency-matrices

The following question is from *Introduction to dynamical systems*, written by **Michael Brin** and **Garrett Stuclk**.

Given two non-negative integer square matrices $A, B$, we say $A, B$ are **elementarily strongly shift equivalent** if and only if there exists another two non-negative integer matrices $U, V$ such that $A = UV$ and $B = VU$. Say $A, B$ are **strongly shift equivalent** if and only if there exists a finite sequence of matrices $\{A_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ where $A_1 = A, A_n = B$ such that $A_i$ is elementarily strong shift equivalent to $A_{i+1}$. In the textbook, there is another theorem that says *The edge shift $\Sigma_A^e$ and $\Sigma_B^e$ are topologically conjugate if and only if $A, B$ are strongly shift equivalent* (the definition of *edge shift* can be found [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Symbolic_dynamics).

Now, given $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1\\2 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}3\end{bmatrix}$, we are asked to show that they are strongly shift equivalent. It is obvious that they two are not elementarily strongly shift equivalent (if yes, $U$ must be a three-by-one matrix and $V = U^T$. However, we can try all the non-negative integer three-by-one matrix and find out none of them work). I also tried to, first let $U_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}, V_1 = U_1^T$, then show $A$ is strongly shift equivalent to $U_1V_1$ but could not find another pair of $U, V$ to make this happen. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why $V=U^t$ if $U$ is column vector. Given an arbitrary non-negative column vector $C$ and a non-negative row vector $L$ of size $n\times 1$ and $1\times n$ respectively, by definition, the matrices $LC$ and $CL$ are elementary strongly equivalent, whatever the choices of $C$ and $L$ are....
The main reason why you cannot take $U$ to be a row is that a matrix $LC$ has rank $0$ or $1$, while $A$ has rank $2$.

Comment: Let
$$
U_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 \\
  2 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
V_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have
$A=A_1=U_1V_1$ and
$$
A_2=V_1U_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 \\
  2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
Let 
$$
U_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  1
\end{pmatrix},
V_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A_2=U_2V_2$ and $[3]=V_2U_2=A_3$.

Comment: @kabenyuk: you should turn this into an answer, maybe expanding a bit on how you found these matrices.